# Mysterious compile error with groovy eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy, compiler-errors, ide

So, I am developing with eclipse 4.2 and groovy 2.3 / jdk 1.6.0_35.
I just worked on one of my classes when suddenly eclipse showed me a dozen compile errors in different classes out of nowhere. It says e.g. it can't find a class in an import statement, although the class is there. Running the code works fine even though the errors are shown. If I add a comment to one of the classes and save it, some errors go away but may come back as soon as I change another (totally different) class.

It also shows me some errors like these:

[image]

error description:
[image]

As you see, the error is totally unrelated (`Optional` is totally independent of any other class, also of course independend of the mentioned classes in the error message). If I add a comment somewhere and save `Optional`, the error goes away but comes back as soon as I save any other class.

I cleaned the project, deleted the bin-directory and restarted eclipse/computer but it didnt' help. Does anyone already experienced this behaviour? How to fix it?

Comment: Errors in Groovy Eclipse sometimes pop out in unexpected places. Its a side effect of how the compiler works. The error is shown here, but its cause actually was somewhere else. The best clue you have for the cause of the failure is the text of the message. Try looking at the classes it mentions (i.e. the "Cobol" ones).

Comment: Another thing that helps in diagnostic is to check whether the error shows only in the editor or also in the "Problems" view. If the former than its not a problem compiling your code, but a discrepancy between "Reconciling" (a kind of limited compile for editor support) and actual compilation. If problem is only in reconciling it is some kind of bug and probably would be good to report it on Greclipse issue tracker: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem and error was in file above one with compilation error. So try to comment file before and check if this solve problem.